# Spring MVC controller's ajax method

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I have some web application that uses jQuery to send AJAX requests to server. One of the methods (in controller) returns a ModelAndView object that can be a html code or JSON object - depends on errors existing. The input parameters of thid method is JSON array (form).
The method definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generate", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = BaseController.AJAX_HEADER)
public ModelAndView generate(@RequestBody HandlingReportForm form, HttpServletResponse response) {...}
```

The jQuery method looks like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': callback,
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

There is no problem when server returns a JSON array. The problem comes when server's response is html. I receive a "parseerror" exception. I suppose that jQuery trying to parse the response string to JSON. AM I right?
How can I disable that automatic parsing? Is there another way to implement such universal method?

Thank you
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataType has been mentioned as json, hence JQuery would try to interpret the response as an json object.

[JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation -

*dataType - "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)*

Its better to return a single response format.

You can also exclude the dataType argument.
*If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).*

Comment: Yes, I removed a dataType, so everything returns as string. Then I convert it to JSON if necessary. Thank you

Comment: By the way, it seems that latest versions of jQuery (I am using 1.6.2) can parse JSON object automatically even without specifing dataType attribute.

Comment: yup it interprets the datatype and should convert the data.